# Breaking a While Loop with User Input

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to build a list that continual adds to the list until the user inputs an empty string.

I've been trying to break the while loop with len() == 0: break

```
# Create the lsit
prep = []

# Add to list until enter empty str
while True:
    prep.append(input('add to list: '))
    if len(input) == 0:
        break

#print list
print(prep)
```

In my head this should break the while loop and the program should then print the appended list? But once I enter any input (including an empty sting) I get this Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\patri\prep_list1.py", line 4, in <module>
    if len(input) == 0:
       ^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: object of type 'builtin_function_or_method' has no len()
PS C:\Users\patri>
```

Comment: Did you mean to write `len(input())` or `len(prep[-1])`?

Comment: You need to either call `input()` or save the input from the previous line to a variable and compare that.

Answer (score 1):

`len(input)` will not tell you the length of the last input. You need to put it into a variable to test it.

```
while True:
    val = input('add to list')
    if len(val) == 0:
        break
    prep.append(val)
```

This also avoids putting the empty input into the list before testing.

You can combine assigning the variable with testing the length using the [walrus operator](https://realpython.com/python-walrus-operator/):

```
while val := input('add to list'):
    prep.append(val)
```